# Meta box with front-end styling

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, user-meta, post-meta

I have a specific *Gallery* post of products that I release at the start of every Monday on my website, which differs from my other *Gallery* posts.

These types of *Gallery* post don't require the *Authors Bio* or post *Tags*.

---

I have been manually going into the `style.css` file and changing it to read:

```
body.postid-9840 div.post-tags,
body.postid-9840 div#author-bio {display: none;}
```

However, this process has become time-consuming and is starting to take up a lot of room in my `style.css` file.

---

Is there a way I can display a *Meta* checkbox at the bottom of my *Gallery* post screen, that when clicked, is able to turn off/hide the *Authors Bio* and post *Tags* from being displayed on the front-end?

---

For example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Please show us what _you_ have tried so far.

Comment: Please don't use pastebins. File an [edit] and put the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a checkbox, you can code one if you want, but you can use the default Custom Fields.

Make sure they are enabled:

[image]

Then add some data on the posts you want to have a specific style on, you will need to add this to each post you want to have set to `display: none;`:
[image]

Now inside the loop of your page you will add that value as a CSS class:

```
 // loop starts
 <?php $authoryes = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'authordisplay', true ); ?>
 <div class="page<?php echo $authoryes; ?>">
 // rest of the loop
 </div>
```

So now you just have to add one style to your CSS for `.pageauthor`

You should probably use a more unique name than "author" for the value, I did this fast.